# angular 2: validate a input field with built in validators

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angular

Angular 2 has some built in validators like *maxlength*, *minlength* and *pattern*. i have written this line of code:

```
 <input id="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile"
   minlength="10">
```

If a user enters for example a 5-digit number and goes to the next input field an error should appear that says like 'The number you have typed is incorrect'.

How to do that with Angular 2?

In angular 1 is very easy like this

```
         <p class="help-block" ng-if="editForm.mobile.$error.minlength">

          <h3>This field is required to be at least 10 characters.</h3>
         </p>
```

Comment: This is explained in the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seems to work. I did this:

  `<p class="help-block" *ngIf="mobile.errors">
                                    This field is required to be at least 10 characters.
                            </p>`

I also tried this:

`<p class="help-block" *ngIf="mobile.errors.minlength">
                                    This field is required to be at least 10 characters.
                            </p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using template driven forms then you need to change your input to have an `ngModel` binding to a variable in your component, and a template variable name:

```
<input id="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" [(ngModel)]="mobileNumber"
   #mobile="ngModel" minlength="10">
<div *ngIf="mobile.errors?.minlength">Minimum length not met</div>
```

That link in the comment on your question is very good reading for understanding this, as it has instructions such as

> We set the name attribute of the input box to "mobile" so Angular can
>   track this input element and associate it with an Angular form control
>   called name in its internal control model.
>
> We use the [(ngModel)] directive to two-way data bind the input box to
>   the hero.name property.
>
> We set a template variable (#mobile) to the value "ngModel" (always
>   ngModel). This gives us a reference to the Angular NgModel directive
>   associated with this control that we can use in the template to check
>   for control states such as valid and dirty.

Here's a plunker you can muck about with: http://plnkr.co/edit/dxtIkZI1dhp07lvega5P

Comment: this has worked for me! i just have another question. This code gives feedback directly. So when a user is typing, the feedback appears immediately. It is better to give feedback when a user leave the input field. How to achieve this functionality?